# Mocha how to use utils function stackTraceFilter()

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, stack-trace

i try to use the mocha utils [stackTraceFilter()](https://mochajs.org/api/module-utils.html#.stackTraceFilter) function

but i cannot find an example usage case where someone explains how to use it in ones test. I found the official tests here: [link](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/668b541090c84b66a701823b30f6880d3fc0f2b9/test/node-unit/stack-trace-filter.spec.js)

But how can i implement it in my tests, which somehow look like that:

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import 'mocha'

import { main, main2 } from './'

describe.only('index.ts', async () => {

    it('should start a job', async () => {
        // const R_RUN_MAIN = await main()

        await main2()
        // TEST
        expect(1).to.equal(1) // fails

    })

})
```

In the tests i can see the line

```
expect(filter(stack.join('\n')), 'to be', stack.slice(0, 3).join('\n'));
```

But how do i get the Stack for my test?

```
expect(1).to.equal(1) // fails
```

or in general, how do i get the stack and initialize the filter function for the whole file when, for example, code from an imported file is already failing and creating a long stack trace?

## UPDATE (2018.08.15)

so i got mocha running in a programmatic way:

```
export {}
import * as MOCHA from 'mocha'

async function run() {
    const mocha = new MOCHA({
        reporter: 'progress',
        reporterOptions: {
            verbose: true,
        },
    })
    mocha.addFile(`./src/utils/mocha/index.spec.ts`)
    const R = mocha.run((failures) => {
        process.on('exit', () => {
            process.exit(failures)
        })
    })

}

run()
```

I dont know where to add and run the Filter function?

`const filter =  MOCHA.utils.stackTraceFilter`

Answer (score 0):

The `stackTraceFilter()` function in mocha isn't meant to filter your code, but rather the mocha internals that in theory shouldn't be relevant to your tests. You can view the [source code](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/a7581542c879722986afecaa578e3734be3045ed/lib/utils.js#L708), but to sum it up it just filters out 'mocha' and 'node' lines from the stack, depending on the environment you're in.

I think what you're looking for could be accomplished through the package [StackTraceJS](https://www.stacktracejs.com/), which allows you to grab a stack from anywhere, and do what you want with it. We created a custom [reporter](https://github.com/netpoint-gmbh/mochaterial) for mocha which uses it, and it works quite well.

So, using the example from their site:

```
StackTrace.get()
   .then(function(stack){
      // you now have a stack, and can filter as you wish
    })
   .catch(function(err){});
```